# C: message queue getting wrong data

Tags: c

I have this message queue where I send and receive data. Somehow I am getting wrong data and can't figure it out why.

The struct that I send and receive:

```
struct messageTaxi {
    long mtype;
    pid_t taxiPid;
    long longhest_route_byTime;
    int number_request;
    int longhest_route_byCell;
};
```

Struct length:

```
int msgLength = sizeof(int) * 2 + sizeof(pid_t) + sizeof(long);
```

The code:

```
void handle_signal(int signal) {
    struct messageTaxi msgTaxi;
    struct msqid_ds my_queue_stat;
    int msgLength = sizeof(int) * 2 + sizeof(pid_t) + sizeof(long);
    int num_bytes = 0;

    shmId = getSharedMemoryId(sharedStruct, SHM_KEY);

    sharedStruct = shmat(shmId, NULL, 0);
    int msqid = getMsgId(MESSAGE_QUEUE_KEY);

    if (signal == SIGALRM) {
        msgctl(msqid, IPC_STAT, &my_queue_stat);

        while (my_queue_stat.msg_qnum != 0) {
            num_bytes = msgrcv(msqid, &msgTaxi, msgLength, 0, 0);
            if (num_bytes >= 0) {
                if (msgTaxi.mtype == TYPE_TAXI_SUCCESS) {
                    printf("%d\n", num_bytes);
                    printf("msgTaxi.number_request %d\n", msgTaxi.number_request);
                    printf("msgTaxi.longhest_route_byTime %ld\n", msgTaxi.longhest_route_byTime);
  ---> this is wrong data print
                    printf("msgTaxi.longhest_route_byCell %d\n", msgTaxi.longhest_route_byCell);
                }
                msgctl(msqid, IPC_STAT, &my_queue_stat);
            }
        } else
        if (signal == SIGINT) {
            removedIpcStruct(shmId, semId_Cell, semId_Sync, msqid, msq_sources_id);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

---

output:

```
20
msgTaxi.number_request 445
msgTaxi.longhest_route_byTime 2
msgTaxi.longhest_route_byCell 0
20
msgTaxi.number_request 445
msgTaxi.longhest_route_byTime 2
msgTaxi.longhest_route_byCell 0
20
msgTaxi.number_request 445
msgTaxi.longhest_route_byTime 2
msgTaxi.longhest_route_byCell 0
20
[...]
```

---

how I send the data:

```
    msg_stats.mtype = TYPE_TAXI_SUCCESS;
   // printf("cells= %d time = %li\n", this_longhest_route_cells, this_longhest_route_time);
    msg_stats.taxiPid= getpid();
    msg_stats.longhest_route_byCell =1; //this_longhest_route_cells; // output of this is wrong
    msg_stats.longhest_route_byTime =2 ;//this_longhest_route_time;
    //printf("cells= %d time = %li\n", msg_stats.longhest_route_byCell, msg_stats.longhest_route_byTime);
    msg_stats.number_request = 445;
    msgsnd(msg_id, &msg_stats, msg_snd_length, 0);
```

Comment: What do you get if you print the value of `sizeof(messageTaxi)`. Maybe it's not what you think. But, even without any 'padding', I can count **two** `long` members, so why don't you multiply `sizeof(long)` by 2?

Comment: @AdrianMole for what i have been told is that you don't include the mtype in the length - /* The length is essentially the size of the structure minus sizeof(mtype) */

Comment: In addition to using the wrong structure size and not doing enough error checking, stdio and sysv ipc functions can't be safely used in signal handlers. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html